# Вывод товаров из Бд laravel ошибка

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

При выводе товара из бд происходит ошибка
(4/4) ErrorException
Undefined variable: menus (View: D:\OSPanel\domains\blog\resources\views\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\OSPanel\domains\blog\resources\views\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\OSPanel\domains\blog\resources\views\sidebar.blade.php), переменная menus это таблица в бд(меню которое выводится), до того как создал новый контроллер вывода товаров меню выводилось хорошо и без ошибок, подскажите может я как то не так понял суть работы этого фрейма!?
Вот код:

```
       //Роуты//
       Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
       Route::get('/', 'MenuController@menu');
       Route::get('/', 'TovarController@tovar');
       Route::get('/contacts', 'SiteController@contacts');
       Route::get('/category/{id}', 'SiteController@category');

       //контроллеры//

       <?php
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        use App\Menu;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;

        class MenuController extends Controller
       {
         public function menu()
       {
        $menus = Menu::all();
        return view('index', compact('menus'));
       }
       }

       <?php
       namespace App\Http\Controllers;
       use App\Tovar;
       use Illuminate\Http\Request;
       class TovarController extends Controller
       {
        public function tovar()
       {
        $tovars = Tovar::all();
        return view('index', compact('tovars'));
       }
       }

       //Модели//

       <?php
       namespace App;
       use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
       class Menu extends Model
      {
       protected $table = 'menus';
      }
      <?php
      namespace App;
      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
      class Tovar extends Model
      {
       protected $table = 'tovars';
      }

     // сам сайдбар, в котором переменная не определенна
     <div class="content__left">
        <a href="" class="content__left-title">Каталог товаров</a>
        @foreach ($menus as $menu)
        <ul class="left__menu">
            <li class="left__menu-item"><a href="{{url("public/$menu->url")}}">{{ $menu->title }}</a></li>
        </ul>@endforeach
    </div>
```

Comment: измените имя sidebar.blade.php на index.blade.php и проверьте...

Comment: Дело в том что имя index.blade.php у меня уже существует

Comment: у вас  переменная menus не определено в (sidebar) поэтому и ошибка.

Comment: <div class="content__left">

   <a href="" class="content__left-title">Каталог товаров</a>
   @foreach ($menus as $menu)
   <ul class="left__menu">
    <li class="left__menu-item"><a href="{{url("public/$menu->url")}}">{{ $menu->title }}</a></li>
   </ul>@endforeach
  </div>

Comment: Она стала не определенна после добавления нового контроллера и модели

Comment: добавьте код вюшки

Comment: Добавил вьюшку sidebar.blade.php

Comment: __return view('index', compact('menus'));__  вот тут поменяй значение index на sidebar таким образом и проверь  __return view('sidebar', compact('menus'));__

Comment: Поменял но не помогло

Comment: Переменные работают почему то только по отдельности... Пробывал переменную menus заменить на tovars и все работает(выводит значения которые я вбил в таблицу tovars) и наоборот если tovars убрать то menus работает